# Painted wood on surface

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials, photorealism

Is there a way to make a painted material from the picture below? All answers are welcome.

[image]

---

I know it. So, the image texture for the base colour is using a *ColorRamp* node, linked into a *Principled BSDF* node.

Here is a screen capture of the nodes:

[image]
[image]

and the preview photo:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean exactly? Can't you use it in an Image Texture node?

Comment: I wonder how they moved my answer to the question.

Comment: iKlsR has edited your post but he lost your original picture, you can edit it again and add it if you want

Comment: Do you still need help with this, @22melloja? If yes, can you specify what's the issue? You seem to have managed to get the colors working, you only need to keep tweaking the ColorRamp to get the desired contrast. The Mapping seems weird, but we'd need to see the UV, plus Texture Coordinates and Mapping nodes to see what's going on. Edit your question this time to add the information.

Comment: There! @Rhaenys